# Is there a possibility to access the video description in youtube_dl(Python package, not command line tool) without having to download .info.json?

Tags: python, youtube-dl

Well, the question is mostly above. I want to access the video description without having to use writeinfojson.

And no, extract_info doesn't do this!

In the terminology of youtube_dl the "video description" is everything that's in the .info.json-files, written by the `writeinfojson` option.

Comment: sorry I didn't notice the python tag at first, I edited the answer to get the description within python script

Answer (score 0):

yes, there is a function to extract information which include the video description:

```
from youtube_dl import YoutubeDL

ydl = YoutubeDL()
ydl.add_default_info_extractors()
info = ydl.extract_info('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=71PD2f1ogyk', download=False)

print (info['description'])
```

Comment: I meant by using the youtube_dl Python package.

Comment: @csabinho okay, I edited the answer to fully use the youtube_dl Python package

Comment: It does by far not include everything that's in the .info.json-file... Also: I already mentioned it above...

Comment: @csabinho this is what you asked for in the question. if you have a new question ask it separately

Comment: Well. I asked for the whole description. Maybe I used a misleading terminology. But this seems to be the terminology of youtube_dl.